# How to change status and update account?

Tags: 8, users

How can i change status to 0 and update an existing user account?

Here is the code i tried:

```
$account = \Drupal::currentUser();
$account->status = 0;
$account->save();
```

It gives me error :  Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy::save().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The account proxy class doesn't have a method called `save`. Refer to the API docs.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxy.php/class/AccountProxy/8.2.x

What you want is the [block()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21user%21src%21Entity%21User.php/function/User%3A%3Ablock/8.2.x) method:

```
$account->block();
```

As `$account` should be an instance of [UserInterface](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!user!src!UserInterface.php/interface/UserInterface/8.2.x), returned front [getAccount](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountProxy.php/function/AccountProxy%3A%3AgetAccount/8.2.x) of AccountProxy. But without seeing the rest of the code its hard to see if this is the right approach for what you are trying to do.

If you could get the user account another way, then you could do:

```
$account = \Drupal\user\Entity\User::load('uid arg');
$account->block();
$account->save();
```

Comment: I am using $account = \Drupal::currentUser(); I am not able to understand can you please elaborate.

Comment: Using $account->block() gives Call to undefined method Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxy::block()

Comment: Because currentUser returns an instance of AccountProxyInterface.

Comment: Your answer is IMHO missing the critical part: $acount->id() instead of 'uid arg'